How to chain model binding with where in route
If I have route like this.
Route::get('/users/{user}/posts/{post}', function (User $user, Post $post) {
    return $post;
});

Then If User id 1 has Post id 1,2,3 and User id 2 has Post id 4,5,6.
How to make Post that bind in route return 404. When Post was not create by User like /users/1/posts/4.


If you wish, you may instruct Laravel to scope "child" bindings even when a custom key is not provided. To do so, you may invoke the scopeBindings method when defining your route:

use App\Models\Post;
use App\Models\User;
 
Route::get('/users/{user}/posts/{post}', function (User $user, Post $post) {
    return $post;
})->scopeBindings();

/users/1/posts/1 <- returns the post 1
/users/1/posts/4 <- returns 404
/users/2/posts/4 <- returns the post 4
/users/2/posts/1 <- returns 404

Documentation

It throw an error Method Illuminate\Routing\PendingResourceRegistration::scopeBindings does not exist. 

Which version of Laravel are you using?

Laravel version 11.21.0

Please share your usage of scopeBindings as the function is available for version 11 https://laravel.com/api/11.x/Illuminate/Routing/Route.html#method_scopeBindings

I got it. The problem I used scopeBindings with apiResource, So it didn't work.

So the point is I used scopeBindings chain from Route::resource. So it didn't work
It have to use this way
Route::scopeBindings()->group(function () {
    Route::resource('users.posts', UserPostController::class);
});

It work perfectly.
